# how to choose a list of dictionary with a different possible combinations for image slicing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to get all  values from a list of dictionaries such that it should cover all possible different combination .
for example

```
list = [{'a': 32}, {'b': 2541}, {'c': 530}, {'d': 55}, {'a': 544}, {'b': 44}, {'c': 54}, {'d': 454}, {'a': 42}, {'b': 655}, {'c': 459}, {'d': 665}, {'a': 2145}, {'b': 450}, {'c': 342}, {'d': 186}, ........]
```

I want to select two pair at a time like below

```
image1 = img[2541:55, 32:530]
image2 = img[44:454, 544:54]
```

I want to do this with all other possible combination as well

```
image1 = img[2541:55, 32:530]
image2 = img[655:665, 42:459]
```

like this I can do 12 different pairs 
how can I automate this to get desired values?

Comment: I am having a hard time following your question. What is your `img` variable supposed to represent? Also, I see that `2541:55` is a combination of values from your list of dictionaries, but what are you actually trying to accomplish with that syntax?

Comment: img variable represents image position where cropping is done, syntax is img[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax] here in this example its represented as img[b:d, a:c], sorry for not explaining clearly @benvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would take your list data and create a list where your `img[b:d, a:c]` would be stored:

```
where_you_start = 0
where_you_stop = 12
image = [img[0:0, 0:0] for i in range(where_you_start, where_you_stop)]  # Initialize list


for i in range(where_you_start, where_you_stop):
    img_data = {}
    for elem in list[i * 4:i * 4 + 4]:
        for key, value in elem.items():
            img_data[key] = value

    image[i] = img[img_data['b']:img_data['d'], img_data['a']:img_data['c']]


set1 = (image[1], image[2])
set2 = (image[1], image[3])
...
setn = (image[x], image[y])
```

`where_you_start` is where you want to start create a `img` from the data in your `list`.

`where_you_stop` is where you want to stop.

The code iterates through your defined range and takes the four values in the list:
`list[i * 4:i * 4 + 4]` is responsible for only getting the four values.

To access different sets, select different items in the `image` list

Comment: this worked like a cham, but I can't figure out how this initialization of list  works image = [img[0:0, 0:0] for i in range(where_you_start, where_you_stop)]  # Initialize list
 here how does this syntax works [img[0:0, 0:0]

Comment: i actually never tried it. It's for setting the length of the array and initializing it with an "empty" `img` object. It worked for me with a empty string `""`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all possible combinations, you can use `itertools.product`.

First step is to rearrange all possible values of `'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd'`. Assuming your list repeats every 4 steps, you can put in a dictionary, for clarity purposes, as:

```
l1 = {k: [e.get(k) for e in your_list][i::4] for i, k in enumerate(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
l1
>> 
{'a': [32, 544, 42, 2145],
 'b': [2541, 44, 655, 450],
 'c': [530, 54, 459, 342],
 'd': [55, 454, 665, 186]}
```

Then:

```
from itertools import product
combinations = [c for c in product(*l1.values())]
combinations
>>[(32, 2541, 530, 55),
 (32, 2541, 530, 454),
 (32, 2541, 530, 665),
 (32, 2541, 530, 186)
....
 (2145, 450, 342, 186)]   #256 combinations in this case (4**4)
```

Comment: I want set of possible combination, not individual values. for ex if first set and second set is image1 = img[2541:55, 32:530]
image2 = img[44:454, 544:54] and next possible set is image1 = img[2541:55, 32:530]
image2 = img[655:665, 42:459] like this, I don't want to alter the values of set with other set values llike your example

Comment: Ok, please in that case specify what you mean by "all different combinations" using a [minimum complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)